# Typescript pageObject model - importing an extended class's imports?

Tags: typescript, import, webdriver-io, pageobjects

I have a 'base' page.ts file with these imports

`import { expect as expectChai } from 'chai';`

`import { expect as expectWdio } from '@wdio/globals'`

and export this like

`export default class Page`

I have a pageObject page called homePage.ts and extend like

`export class homePage extends Page`

Question: how can I access expectChai and expectWdio on the homePage.ts without importing these again. There will be many pageObject pages, if I have to import each time it seems redundant.

I couldnt figure out a way of doing this after a some searching

Comment: If you wish to access classes from a library such as chai, it needs imported to the file, else it has no definition. If you want to bypass it, write you methods in homePage that utilise chai, and just call that in your test. Or write a standalone helper class that holds your chai-based methods, and call those